# Is it possible to catch async google API errors?

Tags: google-api, geocomplete

I use the geocomplete gem. It requires the Google API. When the count of requests are more then API limit I have the silent error:

`You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.`

I tried to `try catch` it. But it looks like it is async - it is not possible at all.

Does anybody know the way to catch this type of errors to notify using rollbar or similar.
Thanks!